# Indent by new line in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

By chance I tip some combination on the keyboard and after my RStudio began to indent every new line. How to fix these. I couldn't find anything useful. To make it more clear I bring up an example.

```
a <- "A"
    b <- "B"
    c <- "C"
```

Is anybody aware of how one can fix this problem?

Comment: Most likely, somewhere earlier in your script, something is already indented and RStudio wants to continue with that pattern.

Comment: I also thought so, but even by blank R.Script I have now this problem. It has to be some combination to outdent disactivate it. :(

Answer (score 1):

I was just having this issue and found something that helped.

Since it seems like an indentation issue, highlighting my script where the issue is happening and hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> solved the problem.